# Mac OSX mount smb to /Volumes from script

Tags: macos, applescript, root, mount, smb

I can mount an smb share to /Volumes using the following

```
osascript -e "mount volume \"smb://user:pass@hal/share\""
```

But this only works if I have already logged into the Mac, otherwise I get a "FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer" error.

I can use the mount command to mount to a folder in my home directory, which works whether or not I have logged in:

```
mkdir ~/test
mount -t smbfs //user:pass@hal/share ~/test
```

But I can't do this with /Volumes as it is owned by root. How does the osascript call have the permission to write to a folder owned by root and how can I do the same thing without using AppleScript?

Thank you

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/697/237 for more ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Originally the AppleScript I was using was:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to mount volume "smb://user:pass@hal/share"'
```

This gives a different error and the mount fails when the user has not logged:

```
29:78: execution error: An error of type -610 has occurred. (-610)
```

I found the simpler version that doesn't use Finder when I was composing this question:

```
osascript -e ‘mount volume "smb://user:pass@hal/share”’
```

As I said this also gives an error when the user has not logged in:

```
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
```

BUT it does actually mount the network share in /Volumes, so I can use this and just ignore the error.